# Salesforce Communities Navigation Menu error when adding link to internal page that has more than one word in title

Tags: community-builder, napili

I'm trying to have some of the links on the navigation menu lead to internal pages (topic detail, specifically). However, I've found that an error occurs when I try to link to a topic that has more than one word in its name. For example, a link to the "Nutrition" topic works, but a link to the "Eating Right" topic doesn't.

I think this is because of the fact that the topic url for something with more than one word would be like:

> /topic/0TO190000007CyzGAE/Eating%20Right

I think the issue is specifically the space character (%20), but I don't know where to go from there. I'm not able to arbitrarily change the topics to one word, because it needs to be consistent across channels. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Do you have a code that you are trying to get it working .Please share code snippets so we could help.Thanks

Comment: @MohithShrivastava here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing in the Community Builder. The URL parameters I'm using are from the topic page. [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/VjNHO)